# HTTP response looks empty but Content-Length is high

Tags: google-chrome, http, httprequest, google-chrome-devtools, httpresponse

I am trying to inspect an HTTP request made in my browser with the chrome dev tools. I want to see the response but it seems to be empty (*failed to load data*), whereas the Content-Type is set to 4464326.
Below the HTTP response headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 12:08:30 GMT
ETag: "3ba731138c01f1ad6536bc1d4030cfdd"
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Length: 4464326
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 04 May 2016 13:02:20 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 153069
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, private
X-Served-By: cache-fra1226-FRA
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 2
X-Timer: S1462366940.863431,VS0,VE0
```

Plus, in the timeline, I see a download time of 4.61s so I guess to response was not actually empty. 
[image: http requests timeline]

I also tried with Fiddler but responser is still unavailable. Does someone has an explanation, or even better, knows how I can try to read the response ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see,

```
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Can the chrome dev tools read this type of content?

Comment: Apparently not, but do you know a way to retrieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are streaming a video, the Response panel shows as empty because the request hasn't completed yet. Once completed, it displays "Failed to load response data", since the data is likely to be too large to display as text in the panel.

You could try [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the HTTP response data.